# Cisco VPN client on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: vpn, cisco, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Cisco VPN Client on Ubuntu, but I am facing problems.
So How can I install it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?

Comment: I think http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com would have been better places to ask this question.

Comment: That's probably true but this is already indexed on Google and has the right answer, so let it ride

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Then open network manager and add a new VPN, it should show `Cisco Compatible VPN` in your list now.

Comment: So glad I found this.  Bookmarked!  Works on 16.10.

Comment: to support the anyconnect protocol, also do:
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome

Comment: Is it still possible to import the configuration from pcf file?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the *Cisco AnyConnect Client* for Linux during the last months, which was in general working, but had a few major bugs.
Most important: whenever you disconnected (also by just switching to another network), you would have to completely restart the computer to make the VPN work again.

I now switched to the open source client called *OpenConnect*, which is compatible with Cisco's *AnyConnect SSL VPN* but just works a lot more reliable. To install and enable the VPN, have a look at this: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/lucasjb/oc.html

*Edit: just saw that OpenConnect was already proposed in a comment. Leave this answer here as it provides some additional information and a step-by-step manual*

Answer (score 1):

[OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/index.html) offers an opensource command line alternative to Cisco's GUI:

```
echo "password" | sudo openconnect server --user=username --passwd-on-stdin
```

See here for more details/source I blatantly stole this answer from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043024/how-to-run-openconnect-with-username-and-password-in-a-line-in-the-terminal

Install info here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/connect-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-ubuntu/

1. First run command below to active the TUN module (I didn't need this in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS):

`sudo /sbin/modprobe tun`

1. Install OpenConnect:

`sudo apt-get install openconnect`

2. Run command above or:

`sudo openconnect SERVERADDR`